# Best approach for oldschool 2D zelda-like game

Tags: android

For learning purposes, I would like to code a simple 2D game inspired by Zelda series on the nes/gb.

http://www.5min.com/Video/The-Legend-of-Zelda-a-Link-to-the-Past---Walkthrough-Part-3-89824010 is a nice example.

The player could move on a scrollable view, and when hits defined map limits, like a house door, dungeon, or new zone, load a new specific map.

What would be the best and simplest way to achieve this, specifically for Android devices ? Could you point me to some useful resources, snippets, books.

I've read some begginers stuff about OpenGL ES, but it sounds way too much for what i am willing to do : 2D ; however, im not sure i can handle anything that is bigger than a phone screen with Canvas..

Thanks.

Comment: I see you've tagged Android, does that mean you specifically want to code for an Android platform? Are there any programming languages that you've already used?

Comment: Kai > yes, im editing my question so it'll be clear its android specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to dig into such topics as:

- AI/pathfinding
- Sound
- Game Loop
- Animation
- Game/World timers
- Saving/persisting state
- State machines

Answer (score 3):

Read some stuff on [Tiling in OpenGL](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article1256.asp). Actually pick one of the [many tutorials](http://www.google.com/search?q=Opengl+tile+map) on the web.

Comment: Thanks for your link, i've already digged into the first 10 nehe tutorials ported to android, will read the specifics about tiling.

Comment: nehe tutorials are a great start - good stuff.

Comment: the android port for nehe tutorials : http://insanitydesign.com/wp/projects/nehe-android-ports/